# accept rate exclude count of questions with just self answer

Tags: discussion, accept-rate

I know that the accept rate calculation doesn't take into account the "Closed", 3 day old and answer less questions. But I guess it doesn't exclude the questions that only have a answer given by the asker of the question, which should be the case.

Hope my question is clear.

Comment: Why do you think it should exclude questions with only self-answers?

Comment: Do, you think the user's must also accept their own answers. I feel if these are not accepted, then the accept rate may go down. What do you say?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with someone accepting their own answer. There is no rep reward for it, of course, but if that's the only answer or if none of the other answers ultimately solved the problem, accepting the asker's own post certainly makes sense.

Answer acceptance still carries the same meaning - "this is the answer that best solves the problem in this question" - regardless of who posted it.

So, with that in mind, there's no reason to exclude self-answered questions from the acceptance rate.